# Filter out a member from SSRS (MDX)

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

Ok, So I have a dim called `Employee` that has `Employee_ID` and the `ID` I am trying to filter out from the report table is `&[12345]`.

How would I go about filtering out a record for just that employee ID from my report table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144900) function:

```
Except('a set that contains employees', {'the employee you want to exclude'})
```

Comment: so the 1st set is the set that contains a member from the second set?